# the break points are ignored in my codeblock

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have just installed codeblock and seems my all breakpoints are ignored. I have checked that I have unchecked "strip" and after I see the full compile command I find there is no flag as -s, but still.
This is the first time that I use ubuntu and codeblock and maybe I have overlooked something obvious. Thanks for any help.

```
-------------- Build: Debug in matrix ---------------

g++ -Wall -g  -Wall -g -fexceptions     -c /home/ubuntu/Documents/C++/matrix/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/matrix obj/Debug/main.o    
Output size is 160.36 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: Are you actually starting a debugging session? The output looks like that of the building process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually set-up a debugger, which you can see in the Active debuggers menu? (see screenshot)

If you actually have a debugger, you can start a debugging session from the debug menu. (or use F8 if you have the same shortcuts)

Screenshot link: [Debug Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ2s4.png)
*Can't post image directly here, since my rep is to low.*